# Move an UIImageView to point A to point B while ScrollView is being scrolled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm trying to do an custom indicator in UIPageViewController detect the scroll event and move an indicator (an UIImageView) from position x 0 to position x 15 while the Scrollview is scrolling

```
 -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self.imgIndicador setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES]; //respeita o frame que eu setar, independentemente das constraints

    CGRect alvo = self.pageControl.frame;
    CGFloat posicaoInicial = self.pageControl.frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat posicaoFinal = alvo.origin.x + alvo.size.width;
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.x < posicaoFinal) {
        [self.imgIndicador setFrame:CGRectMake(self.imgIndicador.frame.origin.x + scrollView.contentOffset.x/3.34, self.imgIndicador.frame.origin.y, self.imgIndicador.frame.size.width, self.imgIndicador.frame.size.height)];
    }

    NSLog(@"scrollou %f", scrollView.contentOffset.x);


}
```

Comment: What part of that is causing you trouble?

Comment: If you need help debugging your code you need to give your readers detailed information about how it's failing to work as expected.